# Adding Existing SAPUI5 Applications in HANA Cloud Portal site

Tags: sapui5, hana, sap-cloud-platform

I am new to HANA Cloud portal. I have created a standalone SAPUI5 Application following the below steps:
[SAP HANA Cloud Platform](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?48f1139b379e48f880cc483ea491179e.html)

I have not set any destinations since I am using dummy data for now. The app works fine standalone but when I add it to a site in the HANA cloud portal the application fails with the error "**could not open App.Try again Later**". I have followed the below steps. Please let me know if I have missed put anything:-

1) Created a site from the site directory screen with a blank site temppplate.
               [image]

2) Next I selected the app I want to add into the site from the account apps section in the left navigation inside the **flpportal** service and added it[using the forward icon].
              [image]
3) Then when I try to add it as a menu configuration it shows up in the list and gets added but when I publish the site I get the above error mentioned.

Am I missing any step or doing it wrong altogether? BTW I am using a HANA trial account for now.
Also, I would like to know whether this is the correct way to do it. Also, any documentation on the same will be helpful

Adding the error description. The name of the app is **Kpidemo**:
[image]

Comment: Hi Deepak, you are mixing some things up. Are you talking about the "HANA Cloud Portal" or the "HANA Cloud Platform"? (if you use https://account.hanatrial.ondemand.com/cockpit for your app configuration, then you are using HANA Cloud Platform)

Comment: Hi Hoffman, I am using flpportal service to add the app to my site but before that I created the app in webide and deployed it to HANA cloud platform. Is that the correct way? I will add a better screenshot for your reference.

Comment: Deepak, can you open the Developer Tools of your Browser and copy the error you get when you try to open the App?

Comment: All right, I'm going to state the obvious: Ctrl+F5 sometimes does the trick for me - if my session has expired then the app needs to log back in. Failing that, I would try running my app with the Web IDE, then deploying it to the Fiori Launchpad from there (right click your project name in the Web IDE - Deploy - Register with SAP Fiori Launchpad).

Comment: I have added the screen shot of my portal site and the error screen.